# manually contacting DHCP server?

Tags: router, dhcp

I have just started to read up on networking and I don't get this DHCP stuff...
For past few hours I have been trying to find out how my computer talks to DHCP in order to get its IPs and all I understood is that my router is some sort of DHCP that gives private IPs. I am wondering if there is a way to contact DHCP server manually from my computer in order to bypass the router, but few of things that I already said made me believe that my router is DHCP server (for 255.255.255.0 at least).
So what is it? Is my plan feasible, and how about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, a router can work in 2 modes:

1. work as a DHCP server
2. work as a transfer station between your PC and a DHCP server

The second mode called DHCP Relay Agent. If your router is working as a DHCP server and you want to bypass it, you should setup another physical connection. Otherwise, setting it up as a DCHP Relay Agent.

Answer (score 0):

The DHCP server is a local device. At home is is a service that runs on your router (99% of the time) and in a business the DHCP Server is normally part of the business's server for easier management.

Your computer talks to DHCP by:

- Your computer asks who the DHCP server is - DHCP discovery) Assigning itself an autoconfiguration IP address and broadcasts UDP request on port 68
- Your router or other server responds with a 'DHCP offer' - an IP address for the client along with other settings like a subnet mask.
- Your PC then requests the IP address that has been offered to it (DHCP request) this is in case there are mutliple DHCP servers with multiple offers
- Your DHCP server finally responds with a DHCP Aknowledgement  - confirming the IP address as well as providing requested options like the address of the router so your computer can access the internet as well as a network name and dns servers.

You can normally change the IP addresses DHCP gives out by going on to the router

You can release and renew your DHCP assigned address by running in command prompt:

```
ipconfig /release

ipconfig /renew
```

Comment: It's not guaranteed that renewing the licence will get a new IP address though. Also important to make sure that the device is not set to have a static internal address on the router config, in a business application mostly.